# Using ISO Year Week or ISO Week with Date Range in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I am currently trying to setup and display our marketing data in google data studio.

I have 4 columns in Sheets with our cost pr channel pr week.
I am able to setup a Time series chart where the data from the sheet is perfectly represented, but as soon as I try to select a date range, the chart fails.

I have tried every format and every setting, and is there no way to filter the data with a date range, without having specific dates?

Here is the google sheets data that I use:

| ISO Year Week | Week | Channel | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202101 | 1 | Cost pr. Opportunity for AdWords | €0.00 |
| 202101 | 1 | Cost pr. Opportunity for Bing | - |
| 202101 | 1 | Cost pr. Opportunity for Facebook | €0.00 |
| 202101 | 1 | Cost pr. Opportunity for LinkedIn | €0.00 |
| 202102 | 2 | Cost pr. Opportunity for Organic Search | €0.00 |
| 202102 | 2 | Cost pr. Opportunity for AdWords | €0.00 |
| 202102 | 2 | Cost pr. Opportunity for Bing | - |
| 202102 | 2 | Cost pr. Opportunity for Facebook | €0.00 |
| 202102 | 2 | Cost pr. Opportunity for LinkedIn | €0.00 |
| 202103 | 3 | Cost pr. Opportunity for Organic Search | €0.00 |
| 202103 | 3 | Cost pr. Opportunity for AdWords | €0.00 |
| 202103 | 3 | Cost pr. Opportunity for Bing | - |
| 202103 | 3 | Cost pr. Opportunity for Facebook | €0.00 |
| 202103 | 3 | Cost pr. Opportunity for LinkedIn | €0.00 |

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Esben Hornbøll [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Publicly editable Google Data Studio report with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)