# How can I select the most frequent text value in each group?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zbki6iZfQOAoJGtaxh8o1WVuZeSnr0GW708qCywlr5E/edit?usp=sharing) that looks like this:

| Country | Choice |
| --- | --- |
| Brazil | Rock |
| Brazil | Rock |
| Brazil | Paper |
| Peru | Scissors |
| Peru | Scissors |
| Peru | Rock |
| Cuba | Paper |

In the [Data Studio report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/3851a1b1-06d5-4336-9863-f89a8a6cb481), how do I select the most frequent value for each country? The expected result is:

| Country | Choice |
| --- | --- |
| Brazil | Rock |
| Peru | Scissors |
| Cuba | Paper |

In Google Sheets this can be done with this formula:

```
=INDEX(A1:A7,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(A1:A7,A1:A7)),COUNTIF(A1:A7,A1:A7),0))
```

But Google Data Studio does not support [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [pivot table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7516660) could be used, with a limit of 1 row in the `Choice` field so as to see the "**Top 1**" value for each `Country`:

## 1) Pivot Table

### 1.1) Fields

- ***Row Dimension #1***: `Country`
- ***Row Dimension #2***: `Choice`
- ***Metric***: `Record Count`

[image: data_tab_fields]

### 1.2) Sorting

#### Row #1 (sorts `Country`, alphabetically):

- ***Field***: `Country`
- ***Order***: Descending
- ***Number of rows***: Auto

#### Row #2 (sorts by [`COUNT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583207), from highest to lowest):

- ***Field***: `Record Count`
- ***Order***: Descending
- ***Number of rows***: 1

[image: data_tab_sorting]

## 2) Filter

There were 2 `NULL` values in the `Country` field, which can be hidden using the [filter](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291066):

```
Excludes `Country` Is NULL
```

[image: filter_excludes_country_is_null]

## 3) Hide Metric Column

- One way to hide the metric column from viewers is to draw a [shape](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6289367?hl=en) such as a rectangle, over the respective area and then match the colour to that of the background (which is white in this case).
- Another approach (used below) is to simply reduce the width of the pivot table, starting from the side of the metric (right); this method ensures that the scroll bar is also visible to users

#### Additional Notes

The default fields at the data source are:

[image: default_fields_at_data_source]

The GIF uses the field names in the question, which uses shortened versions of the names used in the [data set](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YRIMitOsvoVu9GyseNFam7-002Pw0ZeeWN_yJZjJ5aI/edit?usp=sharing) (this was done by renaming the respective fields at the data source, so as to keep the original names in the data set as is):

- `What country are you from?` was renamed to `Country`
- `Choose one` was renamed to `Choice`

  [image: renamed_fields_at_data_source]
- Also, The `Record Count` field is an [auto generated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9489310#june-7-2018) created in certain connectors such as [Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6370353) and [BigQuery](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6370296), which serves the function of [`COUNT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583207)`(Field)`

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/e20853fb-eb2b-4827-a4ac-dfeb48b27e22) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YRIMitOsvoVu9GyseNFam7-002Pw0ZeeWN_yJZjJ5aI/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: GIF]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed, and explanation is super clear. Is there a way to use the pivot table data (top 1 choice in each country) in other graphs (like a map?)

Comment: @Roy: Not at the moment...the feature (sub categories Top 1, Top 10, etc) is currently limited to pivot tables; had a look at attempting the proposed case and it looks the quickest solution is to make changes at the data set (either another data set with a blend or adding a separate column). Note that it would be a separate question though as it's dependent on the specific data set / connector (I primarily use Google Sheets thus if it's BigQuery hope that a fellow user could help out) as well. Will check if there's any possibility of a way through just data blending (but it doesn't seem like)