# Datastudio Chart Configuration Incomplete when no data present and only headers

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

Good morning,
I have a spreadsheet that currently doesn't have any data in it, only headers.

If I put some dummy data in it, the fields are pulled in with no problem and charts display properly in google studio dash. However, if I remove the data and keep only the headers (waiting for the user to input data entry), all the charts utilizing the particular sheet show 'Chart Configuration Incomplete'. When I view the data source and refresh it, it states all the fields are missing. Only if there is an entry in addition to the headers, the fields show and charts work as expected. Is there a way around this by chance? Why can't the charts just show blank? I have the 'First Row as Headers' selected.

Comment: Mark, [edit] the question with data & details supplemented with images so that it's self contained (See [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)). 1) Inputs (showing both scenarios - 1.1) With data 1.2) No data) ([Copy-Pasted Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Publicly editable Google Data Studio Report 4) Attempt at solving. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a row of dummy data (so all the fields will be added to your source) but then adding a report filter to exclude that entry from the report. You are correct that Data Studio won’t recognize empty fields when creating the data source.