# Google Data Studio Hide Column

Tags: format, conditional-statements, hide, dimension

Can I hide a column (dimension) in a data table?. This dimension is necesary for creating a conditional format, but I want to hide it

Comment: Daniel, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Google Data Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?