# Union Vertical Blending in Data Studio

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, looker-studio

I want to blend several tables into 1 table. All of the tables have the same column so I'm thinking to UNION vertical all of the tables.

My data source is Google Sheets/ Spreadsheets.

The data will look like this:

Table1
| Type | Object    | Amount |
|:---- |:---------:| ------:|
| Tech | PC        | $100   |
| Tech | Keyboard  | $50    |
| Tech | Mouse     | $60    |

Table2
| Type  | Object                  | Amount |
|:----- |:-----------------------:| ------:|
| Sales | Sales Incentives        | $1000  |
| Sales | Meeting with Client     | $400   |
| Sales | Visiting stores         | $80    |

While the desired output would be:
| Type  | Object                  | Amount |
|:----- |:-----------------------:| ------:|
| Sales | Sales Incentives        | $1000  |
| Sales | Meeting with Client     | $400   |
| Sales | Visiting stores         | $80    |
| Tech  | PC                      | $100   |
| Tech  | Keyboard                | $50    |
| Tech  | Mouse                   | $60    |

If you can't see the table you can see the picture here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd2Ux.png)

Anyone can help me with this? Thank you

Comment: tiktik27, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration, Setup & Style tab 4) Report: Publicly editable Google Data Studio 5) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: I've provide you with the table data and the output in the image

Comment: As noted, provide all the tables as Formatted Markdown Tables. Provide a [mre] in the form of a publicly editable Google Data Studio report that reproduces the scenario. Provide a link to the publicly editable Google Sheets with both the data sets (the ones that are used as data sources in the report). Also, what have you tried? Provide an attempt at solving the issue. What's the current and expected chart configuration? Is there a specific expected output in a specific chart?

Answer (score 0):

I just got the the answer:

You can use the blending FULL OUTER JOIN and use the formula:

COALESCE(Name (Source #1),Name (Source #2),Name (Source #3))

You can see full information [here](https://www.wissi.fr/blog/analytics/20220222/how-to-mimic-union-all-operator-with-google-data-studio-and-combine-sets-of-data/)

Thank you for Mehdi Oidjida for the help.

Comment: **Needs Details**: it's unclear exactly what the answer is.... What's Source #1, Source #2....? What's the join configuration? What are the join fields? Provide a Google Data Studio report to elaborate the answer and use visuals to supplement the answer. What's the chart type?

Answer (score 0):

1. add a data blend
2. add the first dataset, the one that will have all the key records, if you are going to use this to get all the keys for your slicer, and make sure the key field or fields (likely dimensions) that you are going to use to tie the datasets together, is/are in a consistent format so you can pair them up with the same fields on the other datasets (ex. if it is a date, make sure the format of the date is consistent accross all your records. Also make sure that you filter your datasets so you don't end up with weird columns or rows with unknown, null, or empty values that are not expected to be so.
3. add the next dataset into the blend, tie the key field or fields together, and determine the join type by using the first dataset as your left table, and make it a left join, you could experiment with full join as well if you have distinct keys on both datasets.
4. as you add a dataset, test to see adding metric fields to your chart and make sure  that you get lines with metric aggregation (sum.. avg.. etc) for all keys with records from both datasets
5. if there are records with keys that do not exist on both tables (for which you might have to use full join), you need to create your own calculated field for your metric and do it using if statements in way that if there's no metric for a dimension (key) on a given ds, return 0, otherwise return the metric (it took me a whole day to figure this out).
6. continue to add datasets and test out that you get your metrics for all your ds's before you end up lumping them up into a total field or something like that. You should see the expected metric coming up before you go into creating the calculated field to add those metrics into a single metric.

Hope it helps