# Loading TEMP TABLES from Big Query into Data Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio, temp-tables

I created a query in Big Query using a script to then visualize in Data Studio.
The query runs correctly into BQ, I can open a Data Studio session but when I save the dashboard, I run into the error *Dataset Configuration Error - Data Studio cannot connect to your data set*.

My query creates 2 temporary tables and then joins them using the `BEGIN ... END;` scripts, more or less like so:

```
BEGIN

CREATE TEMP TABLE <table_1> as SELECT ()
CREATE TEMP TABLE <table_2> as SELECT ()

SELECT <table_1>.*,
<table_2>.*
FROM <table_1>
LEFT JOIN <table_2> 
ON <table_1>.id = <table_2>.id;

END;
```

I would like to visualize the results of the final query into data studio, but when I save the dashboard I get the following error:

[image]

Does it mean that the table doesn't exist anymore since it lives in the session? I am stuck; I would like to have Data Studio to refresh this query in order to be usable in a dashboard.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: XvincX, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Google Data Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: Data Studio does only allow SELECT statements not SQL scripts to be run. Please use `WITH table_1 as (Select ....), table_2 as (Select ....) Select * from table_1  left join table_2  using(id)`