# why do i get an error when i fill in the formula in google data studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I want to make a calculation column that contains sales targets for each month. i get error while filling formula in google data studio.

i get error = invalid formula - Operator ">=" doesn't support DATE >= TEXT. The operator ">=" supports ANY >= ANY.

```
case
    when Order Date>= '2014-01-01' and Order Date<'2015-01-01' then 30000
    when Order Date>= '2015-01-01' and Order Date<'2016-01-01' then 40000    
    else 50000
end
```

what should be the formula?thank you

Comment: Herdi, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with ) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) ) Expected output table ) Chart: Configuration + Setup ) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error ) Report: Publicly editable Google Data Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> invalid formula - Operator ">=" doesn't support DATE >= TEXT.

You may try below expresson.

```sql
case
    when Order Date>= DATE '2014-01-01' and Order Date< DATE '2015-01-01' then 30000
    when Order Date>= DATE '2015-01-01' and Order Date< DATE '2016-01-01' then 40000    
    else 50000
end
```

From [Data Studio Help](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10495775?hl=en):

#### Date literals

> To use literal date and time values in a calculated field, you can precede the value with the appropriate marker:

```
+---------+-----------------------+-----------------+
| Literal | Canonical date format |  Sample usage   |
+---------+-----------------------+-----------------+
| Date    | YYYY-[M]M-[D]D        | DATE '2021-4-1' |
+---------+-----------------------+-----------------+
```