# How to create a field to return the position of an element in the table in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I'm trying to create a ranking, in order to return position 1, position 2, position 3 for example, but also naming the position of each element in this ranking.

| Position | Name | Pontuation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | João | 2000 |
| 2 | Victor | 1950 |
| 3 | Matheus | 1800 |

With google data studio line numbering this would already be possible:

|  | Name | Pontuation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | João | 2000 |
| 2. | Victor | 1950 |
| 3. | Matheus | 1800 |

but when adding a filter to search for names and search for the name "Matheus" it would return as follows:

|  | Name | Pontuation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Matheus | 1800 |

And it would not bring with it its position in this ranking. So, I would like to know how I could create a field that returns this position to create the ranking.

[example in google data studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Lmf.png)

Comment: João Cruz, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Google Data Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: @João, what is your data source? (GSheets? BigQuery? MySQL?) I don't think it is possible to solve this directly in Google Data Studio, but I could direct you to some options depending of your data source.

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz I'm using Gsheet, there is a command that can return the position in Gsheet, but as I want this new field to apply to filters, I'm afraid it won't work to do that in Gsheet. But if there is a solution for this, I would appreciate it! Curiosity: In powerbi there is a command using RANKX to return this ranking field, but I didn't find anything in GDSTUDIO.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done in Google Data Studio because it doesn't store data and it doesn't offer a way to correlate lines as other BI tools may allow.  It only allows you to make simple calculations using data from the same record.

But since you're using Google Sheets, you can add a column to your GSheet with the Rank information.  Then, just add the column to your dashboard.

To achieve this, you may want to use the [RANK formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094098?hl=en).