# Regexp_Extract - Data Studio extract value after second underscore

Tags: regex, extract, looker-studio

I have a simple string separated by underscores from which I need to pull all the values after a specific underscore using a regular expression with the REGEXP_EXTRACT formula in Google Data Studio

The strings look like this:

```
ABC123_DEF456_GHI789-JKL274
```

Basically the values after the second underscore can be alphanumeric or symbols as well.

I need to pull the values after the second underscore. In the case of the example I gave, it would be:

```
GHI789-JKL274
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: MktQuery, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Google Data Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: Would it always be at the end, say after the last underscore? If so, maybe `[^_]+$` would do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(some_field, "^(?:[^_]*_){2}([^_]*)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BYc8S7/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^_]*_){2}` - two occurrences of any zero or more chars other than `_` and then a `_`
- `([^_]*)` - Capturing group #1: zero or more chars other than `_`.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following regex.

```
^(?:.*?_){2}([^_]*)
```

***OR***

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(yourField, "^(?:.*?_){2}([^_]*)")
```

Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G0UOI5/1) for used regex.

***Explanation:*** Adding a detailed explanation for used regex here.

```
^      ##Matching from starting of the value here.
(?:    ##Opening 1 non-capturing group here.
  .*?_ ##Using Lazy match to match till next occurrence of _ here.
){2}   ##Closing non-capturing group here and matching its 2 occurrences.
(      ##Creating 1 and only capturing group here.
 [^_]* ##Matching everything before _ here.
)      ##Closing capturing group here.
```