# How can I make Year field detected as Year in Google Data Studio?

Tags: date, validation, google-sheets, looker-studio

Can Any Expert in Google Data Studio help me with how to make the Software consider a Field in Year which is already in the Year Format ?

1. [Format of the Spreadsheet][image: 1]  That is the format of Data I have in Google Spreadsheets.
2. [Place where I'm trying to convert it to Year][image: 2] Here it only allows me to select it as a Number or Text
3. [Error I am Getting ][image: 3] WHen i select Year , then I'm getting that Error.

I have Tried in Many Ways but i cannot find a solution.

I Believe some else should have also faced this issue. I have done my research on this for a couple of hours and didn't find any resources.

I Only Have 2 Years of Data. So there will be only 2 years, One is 2020 and other is 2021.

Appreciate anyone's help on this.

Comment: Quote the error as text as suggested in [mre].

Comment: @player0 The issue is associated with Google sheets.

Comment: RockstarDPS, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Google Data Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a proper date column in Google sheets. A date column should satisfy `=ISDATE(B1)=TRUE`, where `B1` is where   the first `2021` is. To make a date, you could manually edit in the date in the format: `YYYY-MM-DD` or use

```
=DATE(B1,1,1)
```

or as a array:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(DATE(B:B,1,1))
```

and copy paste the values  in `B:B`.

Alternatively, as the error message says, create a calculated column in data studio:

```
PARSE_DATE("%Y", [Year])
```

`%Y`, because your number only has the year value.