# Dropdown menu to control which series to show in a chart

Tags: looker-studio

It's the first time I use Google Data Studio and I'd like to add a control (dropdown menu) to my report that allows me to control which series to show in a Combo chart.

## 1. Data

Data is organized in a ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-REyoyM0gWM6Pwxxonau4-V-CZbO4CHO7YN347iRezQ/edit?usp=sharing)) as shown below:

| Year | Safer Buildings (Annual) | Safer Buildings (Cumulative) | Safer People (Annual) | Safer People (Cumulative) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 10282 | 100126 | 56461 | 524152 |
| 2020 | 11655 | 89844 | 57425 | 467691 |
| 2019 | 13743 | 78189 | 68120 | 410266 |
| 2018 | 9332 | 64446 | 52807 | 342146 |
| 2017 | 4904 | 55114 | 34971 | 289339 |
| 2016 | 1006 | 50210 | 11928 | 254368 |
| 2015 | 1723 | 49204 | 8317 | 242440 |
| 2014 | 518 | 47481 | 2541 | 234123 |
| 2013 | 7015 | 46963 | 34491 | 231582 |

## 2. Expected output table

I'm not sure a different table is needed besides the one provided above.

## 3. Chart

I created a 'Combo chart' based on the data above, as shown below.

[image]

Chart setup:

[image]

More specifically, I'd like to add a control (dropdown menu) to my report that allows me to select between two entries **'Safer Buildings'** OR **'Safer People'** in a way that:

- If I select **'Safer Buildings'** I will see, in the chart shown in the picture above, the bar chart for *'Safer Buildings (Annual)'* (blue) AND the line chart for *'Safer Buildings (Cumulative)'* (cyan).
- If I select **'Safer People'** I will see, in the chart shown in the picture above, the bar chart for *'Safer People (Annual)'* (magenta) AND the line chart for *'Safer People (Cumulative)'* (orange).

I know I can achieve something similar by switching on 'Optional metrics' but I cannot find a way to implement it with a dropdown menu.

## 4. Issue/Attempt at solving

In order to achieve what I'd like to do. I tried to simplify the task and to focus, initially, only on 2 metrics 'Safer Buildings (Annual)' (bar chart) and 'Safer People (Annual)' (bar chart).

First of all I created a parameter named 'impact_metrics', defined as follows:

[image]

Then, I created a dummy field named 'Impact metrics (dummy)', define as follows:

[image]

Finally, I created another field named 'Test1', defined as follows:

[image]

I went back to the Combo chart and I modified the setup as shown below:

[image]

Now, if I select a different parameter in the 'Parameters' field highlighted by a red rectangle in the picture above, the Combo chart gets updated as expected (see below).

[image]

However, now I don't know:

1. how I can show both the bar chart for *'Safer Buildings (Annual)'* AND the line chart for *'Safer Buildings (Cumulative)'* when selecting 'Safer Buildings' in the 'Parameters' field highlighted by a red rectangle in the picture above.

If I edit 'Test1' field as follows, I get an error (see below).

[image]

2. how can avoiding having to select a parameter in the Combo chart setup and have instead a dropdown menu to do that.

## 5. Report

At [this link](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/abe83b58-fd8b-473e-a191-3027fd91eeb8) you can find the editable Data Studio report.

Any advice is very welcome! Thank you.

Comment: aragornii, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Google Data Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: You need a parameter `set` as a Text list with 0 for buildings and 1 for people.  Then put this parameter in the drop down menu. You need to create four new fields, e.g. `safe_buildings_new` with  `=if(set=0,safe_buildings,null)`

Comment: @Nimantha I edited my post with all the details  you mentioned

Comment: Thanks @Samuel, this is a great advice! However, if I change the the parameter in the chart setup, to chart gets updates as intended, while if I put the parameter in the drop down menu, nothing happens when I select a different entry in the dropdown.

Comment: if in a chart setup a parameter set it, this overwrite the selection of any drop down menu

Comment: Thanks @Samuel, ok but how can I avoiding setting a parameter in the chart setup? I haven't included it but I see it there and I cannot remove it.

Comment: It actually seems that if I assign the `set` parameter to a drow down menu, I'm actually able to control the chart based on the selection, not sure why at the beginning it wasn't working but I might have down something wrong.