# Google Data Studio two set of dates and compare against TODAY

Tags: date, aggregate, looker-studio

I have an extensive database (actually several) showing different dimensions and metrics of projects. For the sake of simplicity, I will use some dummy data to describe my challenge.

1. Sample data set

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRi_Qc3EiDRYfz03S2KYVBHx4wuXdh4yaYCaY1T_HIWBuaR7jeST99UZDSAnmri4WOgM10lQJF9VoCc/pubhtml

| Project ID | Project Name | Code | Planned Finish | Actual Finish | Ongoing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project1 | Project#1 | 337 | 01.10.2022 | 13.12.2022 | Y |
| Project1 | Project#1 | 338 | 03.10.2022 | 14.12.2022 | Y |
| Project1 | Project#1 | 339 | 04.10.2022 | 15.12.2022 | Y |
| Project2 | Project#2 | 370 | 01.05.2017 | 01.05.2017 | N |
| Project2 | Project#2 | 371 | 22.06.2018 | 30.03.2018 | N |
| Project2 | Project#2 | A1030 | 30.10.2020 | 28.10.2020 | N |
| Project2 | Project#2 | A1040 | 01.10.2021 |  | N |
| Project2 | Project#2 | A1050 | 28.10.2021 |  | N |
| Project3 | Project#3 | 404 | 26.09.2016 | 29.08.2016 | N |
| Project3 | Project#3 | 405 | 14.12.2016 | 31.03.2017 | N |
| Project3 | Project#3 | A1020 | 20.03.2023 |  | Y |

2. Expected output

| Project | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Project1 | Ongoing |
| Project2 | Completed |
| Project3 | Ongoing |

3. Chart: Pie chart (preferably)
4. Goal is to find all ongoing projects in the database. This is achieved by checking **Planned Finish** or **Actual Finish** against TODAY and if any date is greater than TODAY, TRUE value is produced.

*Issue a)* Described works in Google Sheet, but in Data Studio empty date cell from GS is showing as 'null' in DS. If any date value is 'null', TRUE value is always produced (expected behaviour - null is ignored). Possible solution (that I have to verify with data owner) would be use of 'IFNULL' to mirror **Planned Finish** to **Actual Finish** if 'null' in **Actual Finish**.

*Issue b)* To mitigate issue a, I have tried using NARY_MAX, but this function doesn't accept dates,

*Issue c)* Results are produced for all sub-projects/phases. How to aggregate results so only main projects (Project1, Project2, etc.) are shown - ref. 2. Expected output?

5. Google Data Studio report
   https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/6e1d666b-0f5b-49a1-a93b-ab071d3d8e1f

In the attached 'Sample data set' table I have a list of 3 projects defined by **Project ID** and/or **Project Name**. Each project has corresponding phases defined by **Code**. Finally, I have two columns with the project finish date - **Planned Finish** and **Actual Finish**. What I'm trying to achieve is a chart with the number of ongoing and completed projects.
Of course, there are a few issues with this data set:
a) Project ID is not a unique value, but if needed this can be easily managed with a new value created by combining Project ID and Code.
b) In some cases a date is missing
In Google Sheet I made a column called **Ongoing** where simple formula =IF(MAX(D2:E2)<TODAY(),"N","Y") is used to check the status for each project phase. From here I can aggregate and finally count **Ongoing** value against the unique project.

So in the example above Project 1 is still ongoing with all 3 phases ongoing, Project to has been completed because all phases are and Project 3 is still ongoing because at least one phase is still ongoing.

Apology for a bit long description, but in my head, the issue seems complex and I wanted to give it a proper explanation :).
Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Gersho, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with ) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) ) Expected output table ) Chart: Configuration + Setup ) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error ) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: I have now also updated #4 and hopefully this meets your needs, but if not I have to ask for your further guidelines.