# Google Workspace, BigQuery and Looker/Data Studio

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio, google-workspace

I wonder if someone is able to help me out here.

My company is a Google Workspace based company, we pipe our data through to BigQuery using the settings within the Admin Panel. That all works fantastically and there is no issue there.

Within BigQuery, one of the data points is time_usec - which is the Epoch time.
In one table (activity), this is done in Micros which is fine as I can transform the data in BigQuery using TIMESTAMP_MICROS(time_usec).

However, in Looker/Data Studio we are bringing the data in its raw format.
I have tried the calculated field `TODATE(time_usec, "MICROS", "%x")` which certainly transforms the data for display purposes but it doesn't appear to work with Date Ranges.

To explain this better:

Here is an example of the data in BigQuery. This is part of the Activity table with:

- `time_usec` being epoch time (in microseconds)
- `email` being the user account (every activity that is logged has a time_usec entry)
- `device_type` being the type of device (everything from Windows machines, to iOS etc)
- `device_model` being the model of the device
- `os_version` being the version of the OS running on the device

To be fair, the data for the most part is irrelevant here (other than the time_usec) but I'm adding it to give a better idea of the type of data.

| time_usec | email | device_type | device_model | os_version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1659952732837000 | new.user.3@somemailservice.com | DESKTOP_CHROME |  | ChromeOs 14816.131.0 |
| 1659952299942000 | some.email@somemailservice.com | WINDOWS | HP EliteBook 850 G5 | Windows 10.0.19044 |
| 1659952366245000 | new.user.3@somemailservice.com | DESKTOP_CHROME |  |  |
| 1659952736142000 | new.user.3@somemailservice.com | DESKTOP_CHROME |  | ChromeOs 14816.131.0 |
| 1659945047719000 | some.email@somemailservice.com | WINDOWS | HP EliteBook 850 G5 | Windows 10.0.19044 |
| 1659959338167000 | another.email@somemailservice.com | DESKTOP_CHROME | HP Elite Dragonfly Chromebook | ChromeOs 14909.100.0 |
| 1659959340697000 | another.email@somemailservice.com | DESKTOP_CHROME | HP Elite Dragonfly Chromebook | ChromeOs 14909.100.0 |
| 1659961092792000 | some.email@somemailservice.com | WINDOWS | HP EliteBook 850 G5 | Windows 10.0.19044 |
| 1659958186331000 | another.email@somemailservice.com | WINDOWS | HP COMPAQ PRO 6305 SFF | Windows 10.0.19044 |
| 1659957469855000 | some.email@somemailservice.com | WINDOWS | HP EliteBook 850 G5 | Windows 10.0.19044 |

Here is how the connection is set up in Looker/Data Studio:
[image: BigQuery connection in Looker Studio]

Here is how the time_usec field in configured in Looker/Data Studio:
[image: Looker Studio Config for time_usec]

Here is the page in Looker/Data Studio:
[image: Page example in Looker Studio]

- The column titled Date with the red underline is using `TODATE(time_usec, "MICROS", "%x")`.

  - This is configured as a Date Range Dimension using the above method, then added as a normal dimension after. For the purpose of displaying a date, this works fine.
- The yellow box gives us the ability to select a date range. In the image it is set to 'Auto date range' and it works fine. However, if I change this to, let's say the last 14 days it returns ***No data*** on the table.

As far as the Data itself is concerned, the time_usec field is set as a Number with no default aggregation. I have seen other questions about this answered in the past, with people saying that you can configure the field to be a Date rather than a number. However, attempting to do so produces the following message:

> Looker Studio can't convert time_usec (Number) to a Date or Date &
> Time because it doesn't recognize the date format.
> Possible solutions:
>
> - Change your data to use a supported format
> - Create a calculated field to convert time_usec to a valid date. For example,
>   to convert "202011" to a date consisting of year and month: Example:
>   PARSE_DATE("%Y%m", time_usec)

I have also tried `PARSE_DATETIME("%x", time_usec)` and `PARSE_DATE("%x", time_usec)` as a calculated field. Again, for the purpose of displaying a date these seem to work fine. However, when then appying the date range it breaks with a message saying:

[image: Error setting the time_usec field to Date in Looker Studio]

Am I doing something wrong here? I would rather not mess with the data at the BigQuery level. And I know I can use custom SQL to do the TIMESTAMP_MICROS(time_usec) then bring it in. But surely there is a better way to do this within Looker/Data Studio?

**EDITED:**
Added an example table with data and some config screenshot.

Comment: SL8t7, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with ) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) ) Expected output table ) Chart: Configuration + Setup ) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error ) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: As noted in the [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74317900/google-workspace-bigquery-and-looker-data-studio#comment131203805_74317900), the question **Needs Details or Clarity**...I am not able to reproduce the issue and the error, `Data set Configuration Error` points towards a [troubleshooting issue](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/faq/7219787), thus (without a [mre]), the issue could also be considered **Not Reproducible or Caused by a Typo**. From a quick look through `PARSE_DATETIME("%x", time_usec)` appears incorrect, thus replace `%x` with `%F` - YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Updated with example data and screenshots showing config. @Nimantha - it's not a typo, %x is a perfectly viable formatting option that get's the date in the format of the current locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a formula that's working good on my end with date range control filter as well. please try it

```
DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE(CAST(Time Only/86400000000 as INT64))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a long time for a solution to my similar problem.

I had the time in Unix microseconds. This is how I converted it to a date:

```
PARSE_DATETIME("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", CONCAT(DAY(time_usec, "MICROS"),"-",MONTH(time_usec, "MICROS"),"-",YEAR(time_usec, "MICROS")," ",HOUR(time_usec, "MICROS"),":",MINUTE(time_usec, "MICROS"),":",SECOND(time_usec, "MICROS")))
```