# How can I exclude previous months of the selected month in Looker Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to create a month on month bar charts. When the user selects a month bar in another chart or when she tries to filter to one particular month, it should show bar of selected month as well as bars of subsequent months.

I thought that it would be good to generate a list of months from selected month to the end of year and have it as a dimension (x axis).
For instance, the selected month is November. So I should have a list of month from November to December.

To get the end of year:
`month(datetime_add(BillingDate,interval 12-month(BillingDate) month))` -- value is December

However, I am stuck on how to to generate the list of month.

Comment: user17239308, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with ) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) ) Expected output table ) Chart: Configuration + Setup ) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error ) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score -1):

Create a date column in your dataset, ideally at a day level or if the data is already aggregated, set to the first of the month.  Then create a date dimension_group in Looker with month as a timeframe and datatype of date.

```
  dimension_group: BillingDateDate {
    type: time
    timeframes: [

      date,
      week,
      month,
      year
    ]
    convert_tz: no
    datatype: date
    sql: ${TABLE}.BillingDate ;;
  }
```

then in your Looker dashboard, create a filter and use the BillingMonth field (generated from your dimension group) to filter the month on or after the required month
[image: Looker month filter]

Comment: **NOTE**: It appears that the question was accidently tagged [tag:Looker], while it's about [tag:Looker-Studio] (as noted in the title); edited the question for clarity by removing the respective tag