# Convert SQL to REGEX to Data Studio

Tags: sql, looker-studio

I am new to working in Google Data Studio. I am trying to do a case when on some data but all I have is the SQL.

Here are the examples of what I am working with. I know this is not the best way to create this example. I normally use work with making queries so these examples are new to me.

---

CREATE TABLE #botdata(botstatus varchar(255))

insert into #botdata (botstatus)
values ('0|3900000:3900037:3900999:BOT-ANOMALY-HEADER|undefined|false')

insert into #botdata (botstatus)
values ('1|3900037|undefined|false')

insert into #botdata (botstatus)
values ('0|3900005:3900024|undefined|')

---

I am making the above into groups in SQL using a query but I need this same query to be formatted in Google Data Studio and I am not sure how

```
select case when botstatus like '1|%' OR (botstatus like '0|%' and botstatus like '%BOT-%') then 'BOT'
when botstatus like '0|%'  then 'Regular Visit' else 'Regular Visit NO BOT STATUS'  end as updatedbotstatus, botstatus
from #botdata
```

Having issues since the '|' and '-' are special charters in data studio.

Tried this but not getting the results I need.

```
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH( Bot Status(11) ,'0\\|*') and REGEXP_MATCH(Bot Status(11),'*BOT\\-*') then 'Bot'
ELSE 'Other'
END
```

Comment: Can you maybe provide us a sample data sheet with column of data (upon which this formula needs to be applied) and also the expected output for this data column...

Comment: Alex Silver, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: I will try and work on putting in the data. I thought there would just be a way to convert this case when statement which is working correctly in SQL into something that would work for the same data in data studio. Data studio does not take the case when statements when using a like statement.

Comment: Edits made to the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: are those 4 separate rows of data? if so whats the ideal expected output in this scenario?!

Comment: I cannot get the table to post...the example data and code I provide the the out put I am looking for but in Data Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test it out and lemme know if it needs any revision.

`CASE  WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(regex,'1\\|') OR (REGEXP_CONTAINS(regex,'0\\|') AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(regex,'BOT-')) THEN 'BOT' WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(regex,'0\\|') THEN 'REGULAR VISIT' END`

-

[image]

Comment: From what I can see this is working. I added an ELSE to it since I do have so with NULL values. Thanks so much for this.