# How can I calculate rate (events per minute) in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, looker-studio

I am working on creating a spreadsheet template for a video observation tool that my organization will use. Specifically, we will watch ~20-minute long videos, and record the rate (occurrences per minute) of certain behaviors within subsections of the video. For example, "in the clip from 2:06 to 4:30, the speaker asked the audience an average of 2.5 questions per minute."

I think it would be easiest for users to denote individual clips by providing start and end times (e.g. Start: 22:40 End: 23:02). Users should be able to input a count of certain occurrences, and then the spreadsheet will divide that number by the time elapsed and calculate a rate per minute. That is to say, if the speaker asked 8 questions between the timestamps 22:40 and 24:20, the spreadsheet should return a value of 8/(1.67 minutes) = 4.8 questions per minute.

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to enter time values in Google Sheets without it treating them as actual times in a 24-hour day. For example, 22:40 shouldn't refer to 00:22:40am nor to 10:40pm; I just mean 22 minutes and 40 seconds. I guess in theory, I would need it to treat the End Time as x-many minutes (or fractions of a minute) after a given Start Time, so it would need to calculate the total number of seconds elapsed between two mm:ss values and divide that sum by 60 to get the time elapsed in minutes. Then, I could simply divide the count of occurrences (e.g. 8 questions) by that number (1.67 minutes), and get my answer.

Does anyone have any tips about how this could be done? Thank you so much for your help!!

**Current State:**

**Start Time:** 22:40
**End Time:** 24:20
**Questions Asked:** 8

When I enter =8/(End Time - Start Time), I get 0:00 for some reason. I want it to return 4.8.

Comment: Ryan Buggy, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with ) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) ) Expected output table ) Chart: Configuration + Setup ) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error ) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score 1):

Format those durations as **Format > Number > Duration**. Enter durations complete with elapsed hours, minutes and seconds, as in `0:22:40` and `0:24:20`.

You can then calculate events per minute like this:

`=E2 / 24 / 60 / (T2 - S2)`

...where `E2` is the total number of events, `S2` is the start moment, and `T2` is the end moment.

Format the formula cell as **Format > Number > Number**.

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That worked perfectly. Is it possible to enter times in this format without including the leading hours value? For example, can 22:40 be understood as 22 minutes 40 seconds, or should it always be 00:22:40? Just a minor detail, but would be easier if that's possible!

Comment: That can be done in Apps Script with an `onEdit(e)` simple trigger, but it will probably be a bit complex. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).