# How to create a metric that isn't aggregated (AVG,SUM,etc.) on Google/Looker Studio

Tags: visualization, looker-studio

I'm new to Google/Looker studios. I'm creating a dashboard for a manufacturing plant and we are focusing on the following metrics:

Produced Units

Scheduled Units

Assembly Yield - Calculated by Produced Units/Scheduled Units

I'm breaking down the data by month by assembly line number. I want a sum of the produced and scheduled units for the month, but I don't want an average for the assembly yield. The assembly yield can get skewed if I use an average of each day, so I'd like to do a straight calculation of "produced/scheduled".

The problem is that Google/Looker studios only let me do an average (as shown below). What is the best way to create a straight calculation of "produced/scheduled"?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: AZN_ENT_11, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with ) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) ) Expected output table ) Chart: Configuration + Setup ) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error ) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score 1):

There are three kinds of formulas in Looker Studio:

1. Dimension formula (allows to return a string)
2. Metric formula
3. Metric formula aggregated:
   This returns a field, which includes the aggegation. In your case:

```sql
sum(Produced Units) / sum(Scheduled Units)
```

Let's see in a short example the issue of the averaging of percentages with different size distributions:

| Line | Produced Units | Scheduled Units | Yield |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Line A | 50 | 100 | 50/100=0.50 % |
| Line B | 10 | 10 | 10/10=1.00 % |
| Total | 60 | 110 | 60/110=0.55% |

Doing the average over 0.5% and 1.0% would result in 0.75%, which is the wrong answer for the total yield.