# How to turn combine columns into rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, looker-studio

Hi need help combining columns into a row as follow in the data studio & google sheet

| Account | Accocunt | Sale | Sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A2 | 11 | 12 |

INTO THIS ->

| Account | Accocunt |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 11 |
| A2 | 12 |

Comment: Al Azad, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with ) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) ) Expected output table ) Chart: Configuration + Setup ) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error ) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score 1):

Would a formula like this help?

```
={FLATTEN({A2:A100,C2:C100}),FLATTEN({B2:B100,D2:D100})}
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
={FLATTEN(A2:B100), FLATTEN(C2:D100)}
```