# How to Convert Text type to Date type in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

**I am exstracting Text format data from Firebase and I want to show it in Looker Studio by Date format.**
Now the text data looks like this,

| Sample_Date |
| --- |
| AAA 1/2 |
| AAA 1/17 |
| AAA /12/7 |
| AAA 12/23 |

and the goal is to show YYYY/MM/DD in date format.

| Sample_Date |
| --- |
| 2023/01/02 |
| 2023/01/17 |
| 2022/12/07 |
| 2022/12/23 |

**What I tried:**
So I have exstracted Text data like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm22E.jpg)

To delete unnecessary text (e.g "AAA "and"(W)"),  I've created [New Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2fmo.jpg) and enterd bellow.

```
CASE
WHEN  LENGTH(Sample_Date) = 12 THEN SUBSTR(Sample_Date, -8, 5)
WHEN  LENGTH(Sample_Date) = 11 THEN SUBSTR(Sample_Date, -7, 4)
WHEN  LENGTH(Sample_Date) = 10 THEN SUBSTR(Sample_Date, -6, 3)
ELSE "Other"
END
```

Now the table looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLilY.jpg)
At last to change into Date format, I've created another [fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoJ3j.jpg) and enterd bellow.

```
PARSE_DATE("%m/%d", 1/RejectUnnecessaryText)
```

Finaly the table looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sautj.jpg)

I want to change year to 2023 though, I dont know how.
Here is [Publicly editable sample data of Looker Studio.](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/cc10b60e-7c44-4c0e-81b8-1c63e5f68cb7)

I’d be grateful if you could give me advice.

Comment: Damon, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Nimantha. I have added more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this question by myself.

Field1: Delete unneccesary texts.

```
CASE
WHEN  LENGTH(Sample_Date) = 12 THEN SUBSTR(Sample_Date, -8, 5)
WHEN  LENGTH(Sample_Date) = 11 THEN SUBSTR(Sample_Date, -7, 4)
WHEN  LENGTH(Sample_Date) = 10 THEN SUBSTR(Sample_Date, -6, 3)
ELSE "Other"
END
```

Field2: Extract current year from another Date event.

```
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DateEvent)
```

Field3: Add Field1 a current year and “/".

```
CONCAT( Field2 , “/“ ,  Field1)
```

Field4: Convert text format to date format.

```
PARSE_DATE(“%Y/%m/%d”, Field3)
```

*Please comment if you have any better way.
Thank you.