# Group by 7 day period on DataStudio related to current date

Tags: looker-studio

I need to group dates by week, but relative to the current date, I can't use the "Yearweek" dimension because it always starts on Sunday/Monday and I need more flexibility.

I have come up with kind of a solution, like this:

```
WHEN Date = DATETIME_SUB(TODAY(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) THEN "Week 1"
WHEN Date = DATETIME_SUB(TODAY(), INTERVAL 4 DAY) THEN "Week 1"
WHEN Date = DATETIME_SUB(TODAY(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) THEN "Week 1"
(...)
WHEN Date = DATETIME_SUB(TODAY(), INTERVAL 31 DAY) THEN "Week 4"
END
```

You get the idea...

Is there a more "elegant" way to do this? What if I need 8 weeks? Do I really need to extend this to 56 days?

Edit: I added an [editable Looker Studio](https://lookerstudio.google.com/reporting/fea4fc1f-5793-4439-bc21-af6023500472/page/H41DD) whit this rule to show you, and the [correspondent sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Kj4MyHYm-bXVHS881iQ8lVYMUqHfaqT_6Y4GYHS5G_4/edit#gid=0).

This is what I get, this works absolutely fine, I was just wondering if there was a better way to do it.

[image: grouped by week barchart]

Comment: damiantaubaso, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with ) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) ) Expected output table ) Chart: Configuration + Setup ) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error ) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score 0):

It was as easy as

`when DATE_DIFF(TODAY(), Date) >= 3 and DATE_DIFF(TODAY(), Date) <= 9 then "Week 1"`

and so on...