# Google Looker Studio (Google Data Studio) Aggrigate Record Count Across Columns

Tags: sql, looker-studio

I work in marketing and am using a Google sheet to track "primary story objectives" and "Secondary story objectives" for flexibility when logging materials that we've created. Both columns contain the same defined list of objectives, i.e, "Story Objective Type 1", "Story Objective type 2", etc.

For reporting against our KPIs, however, it doesn't matter whether something is a "primary story" or a "secondary story" we have built in double counting individual records. I'm wondering if it's possible to have Looker Studio count all the story types across the two columns, and return an aggregate count of each story objective, or am I stuck manually running pivot tables and adding them that way.

I tried using a SUM + If statement, but got got stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: Michael Johnson, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table ) Chart: Configuration + Setup ) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error ) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: As noted in the [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75329383/#comment132922546_75329383), the question **Needs Details or Clarity**, thus [edit] it with the necessary details and a [mre]. Also elaborate on #4, specifically the last line in the question which states "*I tried using a SUM + If statement, but got got stuck*". Was there a specific error (if so, what was the message)? If the calculated field worked (no error message), what was the output? This could then be compared with #2 (expected output table). Currently there is lack of specifics on the attempted solution

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
COUNT(CASE
  WHEN "primary story objectives" = "Story Objective Type 1" THEN "Story Objective Type 1"
  WHEN "secondary story objectives" = "Story Objective Type 1" THEN "Story Objective Type 1"
END)
```