# Ungroup other category in data studio charts

Tags: visualization, scatter-plot, looker-studio

I'm designing a scatter plot chart with more than 900 entities and Google Data Studio (or Locker if you prefer) it's grouoping more than 200 entities in the same category, by the name of "other".So the chart its a big blur of one sigle color.How can I ungroup this category and put a different color for some of these 200 entities and delivery a more clear chart?

[This is how the chart looks like with the "others"category grouped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwK8Z.png)

Comment: USilva, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with ) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) ) Expected output table ) Chart: Configuration + Setup ) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error ) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's like a pie chart where it will group under "others" all of the dimensions that exceeds the number of dimensions in the graph settings. You have to choose the graph, go to "style" and there must be a configuration for the amount of bubbles it will show, just raise it to the maximum.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it's not enough, I already put the maximum on the number of bubbles, and until now, I didn't find a way to break up the "other" category into more entities.