# Looker studio change data on link click

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a chart using looker studio, now I need to show the link below chart like

```
day, week, month, quarter, year
```

I got the option of drill down ,but that is showing in dropdown, I need to show like below

[image: like this]

and depending on the option it should change the data in chart,

I don't know if it has any inbuilt feature for this like I heard for granularity, but could not able to do this.

Can someone please guide how to accomplish this, either with any existing feature or by clicking on the link to change the data

Thanks,

Comment: Md. Parvez Alam, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: I have already attached the image showing how I need this

Answer (score 0):

one option is

1. In the dimension for the chart drag in date 5 times
2. Click on the pencil that appears on the left hand side of the top one, change the `name` to year and the change the `type`to year by selecting year from the drop down box
3. Repeat on the other dates for your other date ranges
4. Switch the drill down toggle just below the dimension to on
5. Select the drop down drill down from year
6. On the charts header there should be a drill down symbol, which when clicked drills down

Comment: Ye, that I have seen, but how to show them below chart in one line like, day,week,month,quarter,year

Comment: Sorry, you do no appear to have attacked an  example  of what you are after, only a code snippet showing day, week, month, quarter, year.  If you want a table that shows  running by column data for today, this week, this month, this quarter and this year you just blend the data and filter each table by the data range you want https://blog.dataddo.com/multiple-date-ranges-one-data-studio-table-a-how-to-guide

Comment: I have attached the image by clicking on day it will show the day wise data and so one, currently I am getting in above the header and and with button like, but I want those as link below the chart

Comment: Thanks it's clearer now, in short there is no way for a user to dynamically change  metrics or formatting as looker studio doesn't have the scripting required. there are 2 work arounds I can think off. 1 use optional metrics in the chart but that will put your filters at the top of the graph or to create that chart and page as a template, put what ever controls you have on report level copy it to 5 pages all laid out exactly the same, change the date type in each one and use hyperlinks to provide the user with the same experience. I hope that was helpful