# Data doesn't change in Looker Studio after selecting a date when using BigQuery after exporting Google Analytics 4 data

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio, google-analytics-4

I try to connect data from my BigQuery to Looker Studio using. I set up the data source like this

[image]

Then I set up a pie cart with a date range filter like this

[image]

But whenever I change the date range, the data percentage is still the same.
The data is actually from my Google Analytics 4 (GA4). So the data flow is like this

> GA4 --> BigQuery --> Looker Studio

When I show the data directly from GA4 to Looker Studio (without BigQuery), the data will change after I change the date range

Actually the data in BigQuery is separated based on date like this

[image]

Maybe it will affect? But I don't know how to configure it

What went wrong in here?

Comment: Alexa289, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: If the issue is the reproducible, then it's not the intended behaviour (as BigQuery auto detects date fields as the date field type), and points towards it being a bug. In that case create a Bug Report on the [Looker Studio Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=196095&template=1100266&pli=1) and share a reproducible report (private) with their team (or have a look if there an [existing Bug Report](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/5492224?p=1&q=componentid:196095+status:(open+%7C+new+%7C+assigned+%7C+accepted)+votecount%3E0&s=vote_count:desc&pli=1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you may have the same issue If you connect the data from Google Analytics 4 to Looker studio

```
Google Analytics 4 --> BigQuery --> Looker Studio
```

if you just connect the BigQuery to Looker Studio the way I did above (using `RECENT PROJECT` not `CUSTOM QUERY`), then it is basically the same as run this query

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `yourProject.analytics_0000000000.events_*`
```

if you see the schema/ data type of the query result, all the date is actually in the `STRING` format or timestamp is in the `Integer` format, thats why the looker studio will not recognize it, because it is required to be as a `DATE` format. we should convert it from `STRING` or `Integer`  to `DATE`

I choose to convert the data in BigQuery instead of creating a new calculated field in Looker Studio because it will reduce the BigQuery cost since we scan less data.

in your looker studio, create a new data source and choose `Custom Query` like this

[image]

```
SELECT
  event_name,
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date) as event_date, // <-- convert from string to Date format
  platform,
FROM
  `yourProject.analytics_0000000.events_*`
```

if you want more dimension or metric, you can easily edit the query.

after converting to `DATE`, it will then show the date range dimension if you select the pie cart

[image]