# Why is Looker Studio chart with two valid filters showing "no data"? (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio, google-analytics-4

Using a scorecard chart to show total number of users making a purchase. GA4 data source.

Applying two filters:

1. "customer_type = Webonly"  (from a defined custom event parameter on login event)
2. "event name = purchase"

[screenshot of scorecard with two filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYQMC.png)

[screenshot showing custom dimension in GA4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpYX3.png)

[screenshot showing custom field added to Looker Studio data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKlBf.png)

Each filter works on its own, but when I apply both to the scorecard it returns "no data".

I have checked the filter values against analytics and confirmed everything is formatted correctly (each filter will work correctly applied individually)

Comment: I-70 rally, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with ) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) ) Expected output table ) Chart: Configuration + Setup ) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error ) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because the `customer_type` is in different event.

These two filters are applying at the same time.

So it will look for :

`Who is making a purchase and the customer_type is Webonly within the purchase event`

From this requirement. Might suggest to do the `customer_type` in the user scope parameter or add it on the purchase event.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It does work using an audience segment name ("Purchasers" already defined as default in GA4) and then applying a single event parameter filter to the scorecard. Good solution. 

Wish there was a way to define the filter better directly in Looker Studio to make this function, maybe that functionality will be added in the future (i.e. search for "customer_type=Webonly" where "event name = login", or something similar.)