# How to create one graph with multiple event count in Google Looker Studio

Tags: graph, looker, looker-studio

Creating graph with multiple metric on Google Looker Studio

Hi,

I was trying to create a graph (combination of bar & line graph) on the Google Looker Studio.
X : date
Y : GA4 event count (two different event, let says it's Event A and Event B)

I can set two metrics to "Event Count" but how do i specify that

- metric 1 to show event count of Event A
- metric 2 to show event count of Event B

The filter function only allows me to define the event name condition, but cannot manage the metrics.

Thank you.

Comment: user3463020, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with ) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) ) Expected output table ) Chart: Configuration + Setup ) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error ) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of ways to do this :)

**Filter**
A simple way is to use event count as the measure and the column the the event names as the dimension and add a filter (found at the bottom of the carts setup) to only show the events that you are interested in.

**Create a field** either in the data source or in the chart by clicking on the create field or add field icons (my preference is the Add field as it can be used on many visuals)

Field for call it Event A and add this formula

```
 CASE
        WHEN EVENT_A THEN sum(eventcount)
       
        ELSE "0"

END
```

This should create a field that only has the event count for EVENT A in it and you can replicate this for event B

If you want to do more advanced calculations between the events then **BLEND** create two tables, filter one for Event A and one for Event B and then bind them together by selecting both right clicking and selecting blend, this will create a data table with an event count for event A and an event count for B

Comment: Thank you @Max_Stone, i still dont understand on how to create filter for both measure differently (the filter will be applied to both measures), so i tried your 2nd way on creating field, is that EVENT_A is the name of my event in GA4 ? I've replaced it with the event name in GA4 but it says that it is not available and gives me error.. Hope that you can keep pointing me out.. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: you cant mix metrics with dimensions...