# table chart Looker Studio - different number of rows compared to the data source

Tags: looker-studio

Noticed one problem happening on table chart in Looker Studio, the number of rows shown in Looker Studio is different in comparison with what I have in the data source (BQ).

I limited the number of rows displayed per page in the table chart to 50000, and I have 100000  entries  versus the corresponding data source, BQ, where I have 6352497 rows.

I ran the query from behind my visualisation from Looker Studio, in BQ and the number of rows shown is different from the one from Big Query (less rows in Looker Studio).
My expectation was to have the same number as in BQ.

Anyone else experiencing this ? Do you know if there is a limit for rows shown in a table chart ?

Comment: Gia, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with ) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) ) Expected output table ) Chart: Configuration + Setup ) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error ) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for trouble. There was an issue with BigQuery-LookerStudio connection that is now fixed. It impacted new DataSource created in the beginning of April.

To fix this issue:

1. Go to datasource settings, click edit
2. Rename the datasource, click save
   (if you'd like to keep previous name, edit the name again)

It should trigger refresh of the DataSource and will fix the issue.