# Google data studio how to blend 2 datasource with "or" condition

Tags: looker-studio

I have two bigquery datasource in data studio. I want to perform a joining like id1=ID1 or id2=ID2

How can i archive it using data blending?

Comment: SoT, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with ) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) ) Expected output table ) Chart: Configuration + Setup ) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error ) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)