# Google Lookerstudio (datastudio) stop working: Error Invalid combination of metrics and dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

For almost a year I had a super basic report on Google LookerStudio  (DataStudio) where I could see my events example a page view and how many views did have this specific page

| Title | event | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| slug 1 | view_item | 200 |
| slug 2 | view_item | 127 |

For many months this has worked but suddenly from mid Feb all my reports has stopped working with the only error "Invalid combination of metrics and dimensions".

A couple of screenshot on how basic is the report and the configuration is setup.

[image]

[image]

if I remove the view option from metric I'm able to see all the information regarding Title and event, but obviously I'm not able to know how many occurrence of them have happened.  So the information is there.

Nothing has been modified on my side and I'm not able to get even old records so my guess is something has changed internally on google but I'm not able to find what has changed that made break my report. Any ideas?

Comment: Pablo Aldana, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

On 9th of March they changed the name of the variables my project was using like items views and that was the reason it breaks (even tho they are still visible on the dashboard)

Further detail on their changelog: https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/11521624?hl=en#jan-30-2023

Answer (score 1):

Views can only be used when leveraging the `page_views` event. You can even test this out by dropping a table with `event_name` and using the metric `views`. You will see view counts only on the `page_views` event and nothing else.

I belive this is potentially the root problem. And I suspect that the `item name` field might be causing further issues with your report.

I would switch the metric to `total events` and see if your report will now populate data.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the layout of the data sources is relevant to making the chart work correctly, meaning that the report creator has to make sure the dimensions and metrics are correctly matched from the data source.

For example, I'm using google sheets for some simple charts and it's time-consuming to figure out where to locate data for specific metrics so it doesn't break.