# In looker studio (formally data studio), using GA4 data how do I work out a conversion rate between 2 specific event names

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio, google-analytics-4

im using GA4 in looker studio. I have 2 named events; view and application with a parameter collected against each; name.

I have created a pivot table in looker studio which shows me this data in the following format (with event count as the metric):

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJTgW.png)

This is achieved by including event name, the "name" parameter, and event count and then adding a filter to only include event names "view" and "application".

I want to create an additional column that shows application events divided by view events for each row. How do I go about this in looker studio?

Ive tried several things:

Creating a calculated metric in the table or in the data source itself

`SUM(CASE WHEN Event Name = 'application' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / SUM(CASE WHEN Event Name = 'view' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

This results in 0 for every row

Trying to add a new field for each type of event using this:

`SUM(CASE WHEN Event Name = 'job_application' THEN Event Count ELSE 0 END)`

So I can then simply divide the 2 fields. However this results in an error:

> Sorry, calculated fields can't mix metrics (aggregated values) and dimensions (non-aggregated values). Please check the aggregation types of the fields used in this formula.

Im not really sure what else to try. I know I can achieve this by creating two seperate tables with individual filters and just blending them, however this is super inefficient and id much rather calculate these within the same data source rather than creating new ones if at all possible.

Comment: ash, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: Instead of doing the sums in the calculated metric, use the two statements to create two separate columns. 

Then, create the metric `sum(application_column) / sum(view_column)` and see if you get the same error. You cannot do the calculations and a `case` in the same statement.