# Scatter Chart: Weekday × Time of the day

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I am attempting to set up a scatter chart to track social media performance. The chart should have the following axes:

- **X-axis:** Weekdays, where "1" represents Monday, "2" represents Tuesday, and so on.
- **Y-axis:** Hours of the day.
- Bubble size metric: Average reach of each post.

However, for some reason, it is not functioning as expected:

[image: My current setup]

Here is the data source I’m using:

[image: Weekday is a text field, and Hour is represented in the format HH:mm.]

| Post № | Weekday | Hour | Organic reach |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 06:00 | 210 |
| 2 | 4 | 06:00 | 285 |
| 3 | 6 | 06:00 | 280 |
| 4 | 1 | 05:00 | 162 |
| 5 | 3 | 06:00 | 137 |
| 6 | 5 | 06:00 | 515 |
| 7 | 7 | 05:00 | 145 |
| 8 | 2 | 06:00 | 209 |
| 9 | 4 | 06:00 | 202 |

I tried:

- Changing field format
- Reconnecting the spreadsheet
- Refreshing data

If anyone has any ideas on how I can resolve this issue, I would greatly appreciate your input.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is it possible to provide the sample data in markdown format e.g. using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables so we can copy it for testing purposes?

Comment: matador.lining, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: @Nimantha, I added the sample data.

Comment: @TomSharpe, I added the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I found three issues when I tried to plot your sample data as a bubble chart:

(1) Some weekday / hour combinations are repeated which causes problems

(2) Hour is a time value which stops you from changing the vertical scale

(3) It tries to use the organic reach values as series labels, generating multiple series.

I suggest using a query something like this to address the first two issues, but I could only fix the third one by using the workaround of adding a dummy column with a constant value in it. Interested to know if anyone knows a better way.

```
=ArrayFormula(query({B1:B10,iferror(C1:C10*24,C1:C10),D1:D10},"select Col1,Col2,avg(Col3),1 group by Col1,Col2 Label 1 'Series'",1))
```

The chart setup looks like this:

[image]

and the chart looks like this:

[image]

The vertical scale was adjusted manually.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into that. My goal is to build a Bubble chart that shows the average post reach on Mondays, Tuesdays, and so on, at specific hours. Average is the key, so Weekdays and Hours are intended to repeat. I want to build this in the Looker Studio.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pick up on the Looker Studio tag. Maybe some of the issues and workarounds will still apply, e.g. it's fine to have repeats, but you will need to deal with them appropriately.