# Errors When Editing Data Sources From a Copied GDS Report

Tags: mysql, looker-studio

I created a Looker Studio report as a 'template'.

This report will be used across all 60 of our client accounts.

The data source is our AWS MySQL Database.

My thought was that I can:

1. create copies of this template
2. edit the connections (custom queries) by replacing the current 'client id' with the one in the query.
3. repeat this for all 60 clients

This is the error I get when attempting to edit the data connection:
[image]

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: ah2Bwise, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score -2):

So it turns out, that by default, Looker Studio removes the database password from the data connections when copies of reports are made. The authentication process is then required to restore the data connection.

If this were done via a non-programming method (like Sheets or Excel) this would not be an issue, but given the nature of the data connections (MYSQL, which for the unlearned, is considered programming), it may cause an issue for some users.

Another approach I will be testing is generating the report copies and manipulation of the custom SQL queries via the Looker Studio API. If anyone was wondering, this, like SQL requires programming, and the API documentation can be found within the, wait for it.... developers.google.com subdomain!