# Create a new calculated date field from text in Looker Studio

Tags: datetime, casting, looker-studio

I have a text field named "academic_quarter" that has values in this format:

`2020-2021 Q1`, `2020-2021 Q2`, `2020-2021 Q3` and so on...

I am trying to create a new date field using the first year from academic_quarter, but I keep getting dataset configuration error when I try to chart the new field.

I can extract the first year from that field successfully by using the following expression:

`CAST(SUBSTR(academic_quarter,0,4) AS NUMBER`

This gives me a numerical field with the first year (ex: `2020`). I can chart this new field and perform math aggregation with it. The entire dataset contains valid years. I.e., when I create a table showing all values for that expression, I get 17 results: 2006-2022.

Then I tried to create a date field using that same expression:

`DATE(CAST(SUBSTR(academic_quarter,0,4) AS NUMBER,1,1)`

I thought this would result in a bunch of Jan 1 dates with various years. However, when I try to add a simple table chart with this new date field, I get a "dataset configuration error" (Error ID: e8ecbf6d).

Comment: Chuck King, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so

Why do you use "cast as number" the quarter of the year instead of text? I work in an academic institution, and we separate the year into semesters, like "2022-2";"2023-1";"2023-2", and what we use is

```
SUBSTR(academic_quarter, 1, 4)
```

So all the graphs work without problems with that dimension, for example, a bar graph that shows the average grade per academic year, or in this case, each quarter. I

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).