# Bigquery datasource not showing data on looker studio report

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a view on bigquery with data coming up:

```
SELECT  count(*) FROM operational_control.ficheirosBQ
```

returns the expected 23846 records found.

Data sample:

```
| key             | uploadtime                     | regiao | nucleo | agrup | folder                                                                                            | file                              | filedate   | foldertype | itemtype | itemnumber | doctype | docsubtype | docversion |
|-----------------|--------------------------------|--------|--------|-------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------|------------|------------|----------|------------|---------|------------|------------|
| 502|502|15|sede | 2023-08-07 00:00:00.000000 UTC | 15     | 1506   | 502   | My Drive|1506_JN Norte|15060502_Roriz|Validar                                                     | Justificação do efectivo.xlsx     | 2022-03-27 |
```

The underlying table is partitioned, and the view definition is (probably irrelevant):

```
select distinct concat(m.agrup, '|',  m.itemnumber, '|', m.regiao, '|', m.itemtype) as key, m._PARTITIONTIME as uploadtime, m.*,
ENDS_WITH(folder, "(C)") as automatic

from `operational_control.files` m
inner join 
(
    select nucleo,max(_PARTITIONTIME) maxPARTITIONTIME
    from  `operational_control.files`
    group by nucleo
) t
on m.nucleo=t.nucleo 
and m._PARTITIONTIME = t.maxPARTITIONTIME
```

Using this view a datasource for a looker report, without any email filtering, custom functions or parameters:

[datasource line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtP6C.png)

Connection is apparently straight-forward, as all others are, and it shows all the expected fields:
[datasource connection details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h61G4.png)

When I try to use, in a page without no filters (page properties are clean), with a simple record count, or with a table, no filters, and a single table or scorecard always returns 0. No filter on the controls, or on the page.

Any ideas on where to look for possible inhibiting rules for the data to appear?

I tried reconnecting, removing all filters, etc, and still 0 records show on the report.

Here a sample with a view and a table made from that view. Table works, view does not: [sample report](https://lookerstudio.google.com/reporting/6407e0cb-ddeb-40f5-b2e4-45699db0db9f)

Comment: MAP - CNE, [edit] with data, details & supplementary images so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: Thank you @Nimantha for your help. I found that converting the view to a table everything works. Is it possible that bigquery views have limitations on looker studio? I also tried to connect as custom SQL, with the view definition, and data doesn't show anyway.

Comment: Here's a sample: https://lookerstudio.google.com/reporting/6407e0cb-ddeb-40f5-b2e4-45699db0db9f

Comment: Noted, edit the above in the question (the link is added but not the info in comment #2). Also, edit the input table so that it displays correctly and also - what's the expected output table? Add the current output table as well so that users can better understand the current issue Vs what's required