# Combining values from 2 Google Sheets columns to count all values in the same Graph (Looker Studio)

Tags: looker-studio, looker, google-datatable

I work for a coaching company want to combine values from 2 columns to count all sessions for each coach. In some sessions, there are 2 coaches, but in most there are none. When i go on Looker Studio to count sessions, I can only select Coach or Co Animator.

| Coach | Co-Animator |
| --- | --- |
| Jean |  |
| Jean | Bob |
| Bob | Jean |
| Bob | Fred |
| Jean |  |
| Jean |  |
| Fred | Jean |
| Bob |  |

Link Spreadsheet (example): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1545QSl1S_-eUOJL1DSykLpvcsSHoI4ifb0YoFfwEW1U/edit#gid=0

Link Looker Studio (example): https://lookerstudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/68ca99c0-6815-41e1-8c21-ddcd48ef3920/page/ynsbD/edit

For now, I tried this :

CASE
WHEN Co-animator IS NULL AND Coach/Trainer IS NOT NULL THEN Coach/Trainer
WHEN Co-animator IS NOT NULL AND Coach/Trainer IS NOT NULL THEN Co-animator
ELSE NULL
END

The problem is that when I do this for a new field, when there are 2 coaches at the same time,it will only show the co-animator, instead of counting the Co-Animator AND the coach as separate values.

Can anyone help me with that please ?

Comment: Val: This question **Needs Details or Clarity**, thus [edit] so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: Hello Nimantha, thanks for your answer. I modified everything based on your comment, it should be a bit clearer now I hope.