# Looker Studio : Calculated fields not all visible on bar chart (Updated)

Tags: bar-chart, looker-studio, calculated-field

Updated post with more details as requested.

I have a data source containing list of people with name, age, hair color, size, ... I want to work with the age data.

[Source Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W23AW.png)

| Age |
| --- |
| 50 |
| 33 |
| 37 |
| 33 |
| 13 |
| 15 |
| 36 |
| 10 |
| 5 |
| 15 |
| 16 |
| 46 |
| 19 |
| 17 |
| 36 |
| 44 |
| 32 |
| 38 |
| 3 |

I created calculated fields to fill ages categories : "0-10 y/o", "11-20 y/o", ... by step of 10 years. Everything OK at this stage using CASE ... WHEN.

[Calculated Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8dw6.png)

```
CASE
  WHEN Age>0 AND Age<=10 THEN "0-10 y/o"
  WHEN Age>11 AND Age<=20 THEN "11-20 y/o"
  WHEN Age>21 AND Age<=30 THEN "21-30 y/o"
  WHEN Age>31 THEN ">31 y/o"
END
```

My concern is that I want to be sure that all potential calculated fields are shown on my graph. Sometimes, I have no record in one field - for example no people between 21 and 30 y/o - so on my bar chart, I don't see "21-30 y/o" bar. I want to cover all age categories in my bar chart so, even if no people between 21 and 30 years, I want to see this field in the X-Dimension (like in an age pyramid in demographic studies).

[What I Have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY3ED.png)

| Calculated_Age | RecordCount |
| --- | --- |
| 1-10 y/o | 3 |
| 11-20 y/o | 6 |
| >31 y/o | 10 |

[What I Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGLmH.png)

| Calculated_Age | RecordCount |
| --- | --- |
| 1-10 y/o | 3 |
| 11-20 y/o | 6 |
| 21-30 y/o | 0 |
| >31 y/o | 10 |

Is it possible to force the X-Dimensions names to have all age ranges visible rather than having only age ranges with non zero record count. I use standard Looker Studio (not pro).

I'm beginning with Looker Studio so I tried only everything which is possible in standard. No success. I also tried to force RecordCount at Zero instead of null but also no success.

If don't use calculated fields, and I create a data source with split of data already done - as below - I obtain exactly what I need in term of bar chart. But no dynamic calculation so not interesting for me.

[Modified Data Source with records manually counted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSMHE.png)

| Calculated Age | Record |
| --- | --- |
| 1-10 y/o | 3 |
| 11-20 y/o | 6 |
| 21-30 y/o | 0 |
| >31 y/o | 10 |

Thank you by advance for your support.

Comment: steforom: This question **Needs Details or Clarity**, thus [edit] so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: With the revisions the question is clearer. Note that #5 - a publicly editable Looker Studio will make it easier for all users to easily test out, reproduce and provide solutions to the issue.