# Looker Studio rename output of city metric

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

Some `city` data is being returned with "(not set)" which I've figured out how to filter out via regex BUT I would instead like to change it to something else eg "(Unset Location)" or similar. Is this a possibility?

Comment: Jacksonkr: This question **Needs Details or Clarity**, thus [edit] so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: Could you elaborate on "*which I've figured out how to filter out via regex*'? What was the RegEx used to filter the values? There's a lack of an attempt, and based on the self answer or looks like this question would be considered **Not Reproducible or Caused by a Typo**, as the same RexEx used to filter the values (exclude filter) is what would be used to rename the value as both would focus on capturing that specific name, this the Regex `^\(not set\)$` applies to both cases. Also note that Looker Studio has the option to use the `R` operator to work with Raw String Literals

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Pretty straight forward, as I'd originally hoped. I created a custom dimension and used the following for the `formula` input.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(City, '^\\(not set\\)$','Undetermined')
```

**Steps:**

1. Select "Add dimension"

[image]

2. Select "CREATE FIELD"

[image]

3. Insert Formula

[image]