# Calculate the change in a Bar chart using a separate line

Tags: looker-studio

In Google Looker (DataStudio) I have a bar chart that shows a metric (e.g. installs) on a monthly basis.
I want to add to the chart a line that shows the difference compared to the previous month.

For example, this is the data that produces a bar chart with 3 bars:
|id|month|installs|
|--| --- | --- |
|1 | Jan|1,456|
|2 |Feb|2,123|
|3 |Mar |2,222|

The end result is the bar chart specified and above it a line that shows the change in percentages. The line will have 2 datapoints (for this examples), the first above Feb: 45.8% (2123/1456-1) and the other for Mar: 4.7% (2222/2123-1)

Comment: Tom: This question **Needs Details or Clarity**, thus [edit] so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in case this helps anyone.

1. First duplicate the Metric. And edit the metric with the following parameters:
   Data type: Percent
   Aggregation: Sum
   Comparison calculation: None
   Running calculation: Running percentage data.
2. Change chart type to Combo chart and in the style tab make the second metric into a line rather than bars.