# Data/Looker Studio - Custom Date Range in Calculated Field

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, calculated-columns, looker-studio, date-arithmetic

###### /Edit 1

I created a mockup of the expectation here:

https://lookerstudio.google.com/s/iObb1VOlRGY

While the report above works, the problem I'm having is the date range.   It does not have dates 14, 30, and 365 days from the original post date of the landing page.

How do we get the post date for the landing page?

For now it seems the easiest way is to use a spreadsheet like this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m233aPHPVF0vYLzwYl-rUBvWL3oPDOxtakX0MPpiOFA/edit?usp=sharing

So I'm trying to blending the two data series together, the Google Sheet will be the point of reference for custom date ranges for Analytics to pull pageviews for the table.  How can I make this work?

If there is a better way to arrive at the expectation in Google Data Studio Report for the custom date range, Let me know!

###### /Original Post

So I'm trying to create a table in Data Studio using Google Sheets + Google Analytics.

Google sheet is:

| URL | Page Post Date |
| --- | --- |
| /this-is-a-page-url/ | 10/1/2022 |
| /this-is-also-a-page-url/ | 5/1/2021 |

Table in Looker Studio Needs to Display:

| URL | Page Views 14 days from post date | "" 30 Days | "" 1 Yr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /this-is-a-page-url/ | 5 | 10 | 200 |
| /this-is-also-a-page-url/ | 1 | 50 | 5000 |

My question is,  Is this possible with Data Studio?? (not pro, and not looker)

I have tried nearly everything I can think of to make this work.  Really it's the date range as a calculated field that is the major trouble.  If there is a method for this let me know. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Zach M: This question **Needs Details or Clarity**, thus [edit] so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: "*I'm trying to create a table in Data Studio using Google Sheets + Google Analytics*" - This it would be 2 different data sources right? Could you provide a [MRE] of both the data sets? Would the data need to be joined / blended? What have you tried and what were the issues? Also currently, it appears that at least one field is missing in the input data set as the output has a number field that is missing in the dataset

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: While the links are helpful (#5 from the first comment), the question is still unclear as more details are required. Questions on Stack Overflow need to be self contained. Have a look through the first 3 comments for specifics.

Comment: Its ok @Nimantha.  I know Data studio can not do calculated date ranges, thus what I'm asking is impossible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have tried solving the question in the Looker studio link you shared, https://lookerstudio.google.com/s/iObb1VOlRGY

First, I have created a blend of tables   first Google Analytics ( dimension - Url and date ; metrics - Views), and second Google sheet ( dimension - Url , Date posted) taking Url as left join condition.
Then create a chart field for each condition i.e. 14 days, 30 days etc.

##Condition to use  ---

case
when date_diff(Date, Date Posted)<=14
then Views
else 0
end

I have created a table in report itself.

One more correction you have to parse the date posted column in google Sheets into date as its format is text that will give error. Then use that in formula instead of 14 days date filed.

Comment: The question currently lacks a [MRE] as noted in the comments under the respective question. The Date field is missing. Another field (that contains numbers) is also missing, based on the expected output. This answer is also unclear. What are the fields in the join? What's the join configuration? What is "landing page"? Why is there a blend with Google Analytics and Google Sheets when the question has BigQuery? Could you elaborate on the "*have to parse the date posted column in google Sheets into date as its format is not correct*"? Is it a Typo? What's the issue with the date format?

Comment: I have edited the answer and there is Google sheets present in the question.

Comment: @S-k Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  I believe you have solved this. Going to try this on the big Analytics acct. (I was not converting the date properly. )