# Exclude report level filter on a single visual in looker data studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a filter named intake which affects all the charts on the report. Of all the charts I want intake filter to exclude and not affect Chart 4 as seen in the image. I have two more filters named sub region and org to affect all the charts including chart 4, only when I use intake it should not filter Chart 4 and all the data should be present as is for Chart 4. I have used a single data source for all the charts.

[image]

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: StupendousEnzio This question **Needs Details or Clarity** - [edit] so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: @Nimantha Thank you. I have included an image for more clarity. It will be great if you can point me in the right direction as I am going in circles now.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping (ctrl + G) all the charts 1,2 and 3 and intake filter worked. Just included the same data source that is used by all the charts when you group them together.