# Combochart with combined data over dates and bars showing release dates (hovering the bar should show the app_version). How?

Tags: looker-studio

Using Looker Studio I have created a combochart with combined data showing the ratio between the sum of two events (number of events filtered by event_name) for a GA4 property. The chart shows the ratio over time with the Y-axis showing the ratio of the events over a date range. Now I want to add lines showing app releases for certain dates using a Google Sheet with two columns (date, app_version). When I add this sheet it will plot the release dates as bars but I would like the bar to also show the app_version). Any ideas how to go about doing that?

The bars are showing the count of number of releases (which is always 1 per date) and I would like to be able to detect what app_version is associated with each date the bars are showing for.

Comment: sboss: This question **Needs Details or Clarity**, thus [edit] so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score -1):

Steps to get the required output:

First Step :
Suppose your versions are in this format: ver 1, ver 2, then
create a new field name app_version_number by splitting the app_version and getting a number only like 1, 2 (using a combination of REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT()).

Second Step:
Create another metric/field version_label_for_chart and put the formula as min(app_version_number).

Use the latter one for your chart, you will get the required output.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).