# GA4 - Count users that have fired two specific events

Tags: looker-studio, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to create a scorecard that displays the number of users that have taken two specific actions over the configured time period. However, I can't figure out how to properly filter by these two specific events. I know I can't use an AND condition in an "Include event name" filter because this will always yield a count of 0, since each row in my GA4 dataset is tied to a specific event. I thought maybe I could leverage the "Blend Data" feature, but I have no idea how to properly join the two tables, each filtered by a single event name. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

For additional context, here's a screenshot of a report I started with the [Google Merchandise Store GA4 Sample Data](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/demoAccount?appstate=/p213025502):

[image: GA4 Sample Data Report]

In this example, what I'd like to calculate is "Users who viewed promotion AND added to cart." I expect this number to be smaller than "Users who added to cart."

Comment: gilby: This question **Needs Details or Clarity**, thus [edit] so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: It appears that the GA4 data source doesn't support what I'm trying to do. So, I will either have to find a way to report it directly in GA4, or dump data into BigQuery and do some manual joining.

Answer (score 1):

You can blend two Ga4 data sources, filter dataset1 to event 1, and dataset2 to event 2. Then use cross joins to count the number of users who have either event 1 or event 2. You can also use an active user or a new user as a metric.

[image: cross join 2 datasets]

Answer (score 0):

If you have two event names where you want to count the users, it would be best to leverage RegEx (regular expression) to capture both. I would use the `match regex (ignore case)` and build an expression like this:

`(event_name_1|event_name_2)`

`()` in regEx creates a capture group.

`|` separates each thing you want to match. You can have as many alternatives in the capture group; they just need to be separated by the pipe.

There are other, more complex ways of matching if there are numbers or if part of the names match but this should at least get you what you need.

Comment: A_Patterson: wouldn't this count the number of users that fired either event (not necessarily both), resulting in a metric that is larger than expected?

Comment: Yes, that would match people who did either event. From my understanding, even if you used a blended source, it would still only be a combination of event_1 and event_2 which is essentially the same thing. This doesn't help you now, but have you ever thought of creating an audience on the GA4 side to capture those people who do both?

Comment: I haven't. Just tried it, and it seems promising, but will I be able to report on it in Looker Studio?

Comment: You will be able to use it going forward. It won't solve your current reporting need because it doesn't look back; only forward.