# Google Looker does not show values when data in google sheets source is updated

Tags: json, http-post, google-cloud-dataflow, looker-studio

I'll clarify the problem. My google table receives data from api (See screenshot). After each update, the information is updated and new columns are added. As a result, other columns are shifted in the table. I give an example of the column I am interested in 'result.postings.financial_data.products.1.total_discount_value' . Due to regular updates of information, the column address also changes due to shifting. So google looker can't detect it after updating and requires to update the source fields. Question!!! How can I make it so that when I shift a column with data in google looker I don't have to update the data source fields every time?

Here is the source with information in google tables https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_D0DM-CLUFa-O8amGPRXrFGky3SHdlBG7__YztrUq_s/edit?usp=sharing (if it helps to solve my problem).

Conditional table with data:
| result.postings.financial_data.products.1.total_discount_value | result.postings.financial_data.products.1.total_discount_percent |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 555| 123           |
| 555| 1234|

Or is it possible to make google looker treat all columns as relative instead of absolute?

I don't know what to do in principle. Usually, if a column has a header, it doesn't matter where the column can be located. The main thing is that the column name should not change.

Comment: Igarauskas: This question **Needs Details or Clarity**, thus [edit] so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Comment: of course, it's worth doing

Answer (score 0):

Make a sheet containing the required columns for your looker data source in the first column.

```
result.postings.posting_number  1 Col1
result.postings.order_id        2 Col2
```

Then make the above table using the formula ( `=match(A1, Your_sheet_name!1:1,0) )  and =CONCAT("Col", B1)` in the second and third columns.

Next at the end of the third column use `=concat("Select ",TEXTJOIN(", ",true,C1:C6))`
You will get the output in this format `Select Col1, Col2, Col3`,.....

Now you have the query ready to use.

Create another sheet and put a query.

```
=query({Your_sheet_name!A:ZZ},Sheet2!C7)
```

Replace Sheet2!C7 with your location of query.

Sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14VjyybNYRAVzkk9SUJiMEsPLGU5iLACvCk0JHNetEB8/