# System Error when I share the report with someone others [looker-studio]

Tags: looker-studio

I created 16 charts in Looker Studio's free version using a 7MB CSV file (direct upload). Charts display fine in my account, but when I enable public access and share the link, others see a system error. I refreshed the data connection. The issue occurs when opening with different Google accounts. Help needed.
[looker-studio]

Comment: Swarnavo: This question **Needs Details or Clarity**, thus [edit] so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have set the data credentials to viewer credentials, and viewers do not have access to csv, that's why it gives an error.

Go to your data source and click on edit, you will see data credentials written on top, click on it, if it is set to viewer credentials then replace it with owner credentials. This will solve the problem.
Link to know how credentials work.

https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/6371135?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article