# How to filter NULL results in chart filter?

Tags: data-analysis, looker-studio

I want to use chart filter of Looker studio, but data filtered just TRUE and False result.

How to use condition on chart filter?

[image]

Chart and table not use any filter.

I am expected, that chart will filter data by year and 3 types of result of the column status (true, false, null)

Comment: sbaet: This question **Needs Details or Clarity**, thus [edit] so it's self contained ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176)) with 1) Data: 3-9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Chart: Configuration + Setup 4) Issue: Attempt at solving + Output / Error 5) Report: Publicly editable Looker Studio with 1-4. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test suggestions & the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem with creating new virtual field with following formula:

`Шығын түрі` has 3 values, the chart filter does not filter null values. So I have just make 3 text value.

```
(CASE 
    WHEN Шығын түрі = 'TRUE' THEN
 "Шығын"
    WHEN Шығын түрі = 'FALSE' THEN
 "Сатылым" 
    ELSE "Тірі малдар"
END)
```

Comment: As noted, the question needs a [mre]. This answer is now unclear as there is no context for  the formula provided.